# How to write a pipline for Vite react app with azure devops and azure web app service

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, vite, vite-reactjs

How to deploy Vite React app to azure app service with specific slot name.
I found some. examples but its for the github repository but mine its on Azure DevOps
Any suggestions ?

I have tried my pipline as follow
Basically my pipline is 2 stages. which will build then deploy the app to azure web app service

```
trigger:
  - QA

variables:
  azureSubscription: '{Connection}'
  slotName: 'qa'
  environmentName: 'QA'
  webAppName: '{appName}'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  cacheKey: 'yarn | "$(Agent.OS)" | yarn.lock'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '18.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'

          - script: |
              yarn install
            displayName: 'yarn install'

          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: $(cacheKey)
              path: node_modules
              cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED
            displayName: 'Cache yarn dependencies'

          - script: |
              yarn build
            displayName: 'yarn build'

          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: 'Archive files'
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist'
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: zip
              archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              replaceExistingArchive: true

          - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            artifact: drop

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: $(environmentName)
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                    appType: webAppLinux
                    WebAppName: $(webAppName)
                    SlotName: $(slotName)
                    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
                    RuntimeStack: 'NODE|18-lts'
                    StartupCommand: 'pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon'
```

the build and deploy works but the app crash and not running

Comment: You say "it's crashing and not running". Have you investigated the cause of the crash? What is the error message? What troubleshooting and debugging steps have you taken? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DanielMann you could see the crashinig reason from the pipline
The pipline written wrong I have posted the answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching I found the answer
here is the working version of the pipline
which can build and deploy react app created with Vite

```
trigger:

- main  # This assumes you want to trigger the pipeline on changes to the main branch. Modify as needed.

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  # Use the Ubuntu VM image

variables:
  appName: '{appName}'  # Name of your Azure Web App Service
  buildArtifactStagingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: BuildJob
        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0  # Ensure Node.js is available on the agent
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '18.x'  # Use Node.js version 18.x (or adjust to your preferred version)
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'

          - script: |
              yarn  # Install dependencies
              yarn build  # Build the Vite project for production
            displayName: 'Build Vite React App'

          - task: CopyFiles@2  # Copy built files to staging directory
            inputs:
              sourceFolder: 'dist'  # Vite's default output folder. Adjust if you've customized the output directory.
              targetFolder: '$(buildArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            displayName: 'Copy Built Files to Staging Directory'

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1  # Publish the built assets so they can be picked up by the deployment job
            inputs:
              pathToPublish: '$(buildArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              artifactName: 'drop'
            displayName: 'Publish Build Artifacts'

  - stage: Deploy
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployJob
        environment: 'Production'  # Adjust if you have specific environments set up in Azure DevOps
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureWebApp@1  # Deploy to Azure Web App
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: '{serviceConnection}'  # Your Azure subscription name or service connection name
                    appName: '$(appName)'
                    slotName: 'Production'  # The name of the deployment slot to deploy to
                    package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop'  # Path to the published artifacts
                  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App Service'
```